# SQL correlated query confusion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using the AdventureWorks database for practice but I'm stuck in some correlated query logic. Can someone please help me on this?
The queries below produce different data.

The 1st query returns the customer-wise order date and all orders that have been placed for first order date of each customer.

```
SELECT   t1.SalesOrderID,
         t1.CustomerID,
         (
            SELECT MIN(t2.OrderDate) 
            FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader t2
            WHERE t2.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID
         ) AS orderdate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader t1
```

The 2nd query returns the customer-wise only first order of first date

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2


GO

SELECT   t1.SalesOrderID,
         t1.CustomerID,
         t1.OrderDate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader t1
WHERE t1.OrderDate =
(
      SELECT MIN(t2.OrderDate) 
      FROM   Sales.SalesOrderHeader t2 
      WHERE  t2.customerID = t1.customerID
)
ORDER BY t1.CustomerID
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You should not use correlated subqueries at all for this. You shoudl use joins.  Correlated subqueries run one row at a time instead of as a set and substantially slow down processing. As such it is virtually never a good idea to use one like this.

Comment: That I know . just wanted to know the reason why the above query vary in resut

Answer (score 0):

First query returns orderId, customerId and date of first order from customerId
from all orders - you get those 3 pieces of info per row.

Second query limits the result to a results from first date certain customer placed an order (probably one) in this part:

```
(select MIN(t2.OrderDate) from Sales.SalesOrderHeader t2 Where t2.customerID = t1.customerID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Result of both of these queries will vary..
First query is going to return all records for SalesOrderHeader
Consider u r selecting SalesOrderId, CustomerId and OrderDate from t1 and OrderDate from t2.

Now first query is going to return u all records irrespective of CustomerId with t1.OrderDate for sales order however t2 will return MinOrder date as well for that customer.

```
1, C1, 2011, 2011
2, C1, 2012, 2011
3, C1, 2013, 2011
```

Second query will return only those records for which OrderDate is minimum.

```
1, C1, 2011, 2011
```

Comment: yes you are right. I want know the reason why the second query return single record for each customer even customer has multiple order ID on first date of order .....